# What do I do when I realize that one of my own (upvoted) answers are wrong?

Tags: discussion, wrong-answers

I recently answered what I thought was a quite simple question. The answer was upvoted, but not accepted, and it was the only answer to the question. To my surprise, I realized that I had read the question a little too fast, and that my answer was just plain wrong. I did delete the answer, but I am wondering if that was the best course of action. Would it have been better to leave the answer, with a disclaimer that it was completely wrong? I figure others also had the same answer as me ready, as I got upvoted, and plainly writing that the answer was wrong, and why, might have saved others from doing the same mistake.

So is it ever a good idea to leave an incorrect answer, with a disclaimer, instead of deleting it?

It should also be said that editing the answer to give a correct answer was not an option, as I wasn't able to figure out what the real problem was...

Comment: I wouldn't say "never", because there's always edge cases where it may be helpful to leave a wrong answer (if it's properly noted as wrong and mentioned why). You'll have to look at this on a case-by-case basis. but deleting it is probably the best course of action.

Comment: I think you should edit that answer if you know the correct solution for that otherwise just delete the answer.

Comment: I agree @MadanBhandari, but as i said in the question, I didn't have a correct answer to this question

Comment: Make it correct or delete it if you can't. Points are just points, you'll get some more in the future.

Comment: If you don't have right solution then, you did right by deleting.

Comment: May be make a note yourself either through an edit or a comment that the answer isn't correct but has left in case it is of benefit.

Comment: This really depends on the asked question and what you gave as an answer ... On one occasion, I left my answer as-is, but added a disclaimer to the top mentioning that it doesn't answer the question, but still considered it useful/relevant enough to keep... On a few other occasions, I just deleted it...

Comment: A few years ago I added an answer that I was so ashamed of I deleted my stackoverflow account entirely. It had caused someone several days of pain because it caused a very subtle bug. The answer was an excellent warning / learning opportunity for others though, so I left it up. Months later I needed to ask a question so I created this account. Not saying anyone should do that though.

Comment: Delete it and get the [Disciplined](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) badge.

Comment: Even if you deleted it would be nice and useful if you leave a comment on the question. So the OP would understand why you deleted the answer, and to avoid anybody repost the wrong answer.

Comment: delete and vote to close the question as unclear

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since you don't know the answer - delete your post and add comment/edit to the question that clarifies why approach you took is not an answer. There is no supported way to keep "not an answer" around (you can be tempted to use community Wiki to avoid downvotes, but it is not the right use of CW).

If you know correct answer - edit your post to provide that. You may consider keeping "incorrect" version with explanation when it is applicable as people who land on that question later may need your original solution. In any case you should have at least one sentence that shows why your original approach did not work (otherwise people will try to suggest it again)

If you decide to delete the answer consider editing your post with bold comment "This is wrong because ....." - at least community members with 10K+ point will be able to avoid the same trap or know what is not correct when reviewing new answers.