# My upvoted and accepted WRONG answer

Tags: discussion, support, answers, accepted-answer, upvotes

This is very close to [What do I do when I realize that one of my own (upvoted) answers are wrong?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318957/what-do-i-do-when-i-realize-that-one-of-my-own-upvoted-answers-are-wrong), but not a duplicate.  The difference is that I'm asking about my answer that was upvoted **and accepted** by OP.

Let's assume that I do not know what the right answer is.

What can and should I do?

Comment: That is tricky.  If it was accepted that normally means it helped the OP so it was useful.  I almost think adding a disclaimer to your answer would be the way to go as it helped at least one person.

Comment: Well, you cannot delete it and the moderators are *very* reluctant to delete it for you.  All you can do is edit the answer, apologize and note that it is the wrong answer.  The more you flog yourself the better.

Comment: @NathanOliver - It was a CS homework type of question and my answer looked quite plausible.  OP simply didn't know better.  Since it used obscure tags, no once else chimed in.

Comment: @HansPassant - Is it possible for OP to *unaccept* it as it's the only answer?

Comment: @PM77-1 You can use a custom moderator flag and explain why your answer should be deleted - include that the answer is wrong but you can't delete it because it's accepted.  They _may_ delete it for you when it gets reviewed but there is no guarantee.

Comment: It is possible, but you'll have to get the attention of the OP first.  That doesn't happen too often, new users don't keep their account for very long.  Just try it with a comment on your post, he'll see that in his inbox if he ever logs back in with that account.  I'd recommend "Sorry, this answer is wrong.  Please unmark it as the answer so I can remove it".

Comment: @NathanOliver: The OP _thinks_ it was useful! Apparently in reality it did more harm than good. Especially so as the OP doesn't even realise!

Comment: @PM77-1 There's a difference between your answer being wrong and it being useful. If you are 100% sure is is *both* wrong *and* not useful, then try to get it removed. Otherwise, just add some clarification.

Comment: I had this issue with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3976377/276052). I was frustrated about getting periodical downvotes, so I took the opportunity to sit down, read up on the subject, and edit the answer so that it was correct. Now it's one of my most popular answers. If you have the time and energy, I think that's a nice way out.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

What I recommend is to use a custom flag and explain that you'd like to remove your answer because it is wrong but can't because of the accept vote. We get flags like this all the time.

Despite our reluctance to delete answers flagged as being incorrect by others, I almost always honor the requests made by the answerers themselves. Moderators can't judge the correctness of answers, but if the answerer states that it's wrong and should be removed, I respect that. The only cases where I'll reject flags like this is if someone is in the process of a clear rage-quit or is clearly removing their answer out of spite.

I can see why the system puts a little friction in place to prevent deleting answers that might have been useful to someone else, but I don't think that we need to preserve answers that the owner strongly wants to remove just because of an accept vote by one person.

Comment: see Jeff Bowman's answer below regarding the "danger" of someone re-adding the same incorrect answer on their own or from a cached copy of the Answer being deleted.  I applaud PM 77-1 for not wanting points for an incorrect answer, however the next person might end up being a "points hound" and not asking for help cleaning up.  Does the stack engine allow for "zeroing out" and/or "locking" an ANSWER? (by moderators only, of course)

Comment: If I had a dollar for every answer that was flagged by someone with a competing answer, well, I couldn't retire because the site I moderate is pretty small, but I could still take us out to a halfway decent lunch, assuming I skimped a little on the tip.

Answer (score 15):

You might want to *edit* to explain why the answer is wrong or unsuitable, within the upvoted answer you have, *and leave it up exactly where it is*. If the answer were deleted instead, it is very possible that someone would come right back in and supply it—possibly from memory or cached copies of your own wrong answer!

Though a "don't try this" answer could technically be not-an-answer if phrased a certain way, I can also imagine phrasing it as "*this is a tempting answer, but is wrong; see below for answer and heavy caveats*". This would also provide room for someone else to build off of your answer (*if* there is a similar correct answer), which might make it easier to get a really good answer for both you and the OP. Either way, the community benefits from your research and experience by leaving as much useful information on the page as possible—even if that information is "well, don't try X because Y".

Comment: Excellent point about someone else coming in and re-adding the incorrect answer on their own or from a cached copy.

Comment: @AndrewSteitz - To be honest, I don't think I've ever seen someone do this. The kind of people who would plagiarize an answer generally don't have the reputation required to view deleted answers, and almost all of the answers deleted in this manner have many upvoted comments explaining exactly why they're wrong. I don't see much of a need for editing this into the answer itself before deletion.

Comment: @Brad I'm not even suggesting plagiarism—it might be a properly-credited answer sourced from one of SO's many database-dump clones, as a well-meaning "guess this answer is missing, I'd better add it back". Might not happen all the time, but I don't see anything preventing it.

Comment: I think you make a good point, but the one thing that I would wonder about is if the edited answer stays in then someone else might see the answer accepted and only half read it and then you have another person using a bad answer.  Shame on them if they do, but just trying to look at both sides of the possibilities.

Comment: @BradLarson - although my comment to the Accepted answer explicitly states "points hound", as Jeff Bowman mentioned, it could also be a well-intentioned individual who just makes a mistake.

Comment: @Jimmy - I agree that looking at all possibilities is imperative and I can definitely see your point. To counter that I ask (in a well-meaning, productive way) "should we deny people who take the time to read warnings the insight that the answer is wrong so they should not try it if they find the same answer somewhere else just so that a person who ignores warnings doesn't 'get hurt'?" That sounds like a government tactic, you know, punish the law abiding citizens by outlawing an innocuous activity just because some bad apples turn the activity into a crime.

Comment: @AndrewSteitz - Yes that is a valid point.  Actually more than concerned about the person that did not pay attention I am concerned with the people that have to fix that persons work once they are fired.  I have had to do that before and it is a pain in the butt.  I do agree with your point though.