# An accepted answer with code that no longer works, and unlikely to help future readers

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, legal

Edit: the referenced question has already been deleted

---

<del>The answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17060619/2040040</del>

Three years ago I wrote code to get translated text from Google Translate. Not the paid service, but reading from some magic URL.

For obvious reasons this no longer works.

In fact, it is against Google Terms of Service (emphasis mine):

> Don’t misuse our Services. For example, **don’t** interfere with our Services or **try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide**.

So it's unlikely to help future readers.

Now I realize I probably should not write the code in the first place, and want to delete it. What is the best solution?

- Don't do anything
- Edit the answer and remove the code
- Ask a mod to delete it
- Ask a mod to delete the question altogether
- ...

In the meanwhile I would make some less intrusive edits to the answer, so it would be clear that it does not work and does no good.

Comment: That whole question is  probably best off just getting deleted.

Comment: As Martin said, your answer is the only thing on that question of value, and since it is no longer of value…the obvious solution is to delete the entire question. I've cast a delete vote. Hopefully Meta will come through for us all.

Comment: How about "Edit the answer with text indicating the answer no longer works"?

Comment: My question on the subject: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320480/my-upvoted-and-accepted-wrong-answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think that the bigger problem here is that the question is far too broad. It's asking "how can I translate text?", which is a topic people have spent their entire careers researching.

Of course, libraries and such may exist, but this is asking for an off-site resource, which is also off-topic.

In addition, the premise of the question seems to amount to "how can I circumvent the ToS of this online service"? In general, the Stack Overflow community takes a pretty relaxed attitude to questions that *may* be used for malicious purposes, but in this case it's pretty blatant. It may not warrant closing *on its own*, but it's certainly not contributing to the quality of the question.

As a rule, off-topic questions that have answers that add *some* value to the world should be closed but *not* deleted. We don't want to destroy good content, even if it's considered off-topic.
But in this case I see no such answers, as your answer not only doesn't work but is also legally dubious. This entire question should be deleted, which is exactly what has happened.

Comment: The general question still stands. Assuming the question is fine but the answer is no longer helpful, what should one do?

Comment: @Raphael That's fair enough, although I'm hesitant to modify this answer to add that since that would significantly change the meaning of it...

Answer (score 3):

If your answer is so bad that you are ashamed yourself, and you are *sure* won't help anybody, just delete it: you can always delete your own posts. Except when they are accepted answers, in which case you can still flag it for the moderators (who *can* delete it).

If your answer not perfect but may help somebody, you can edit it to start with a disclaimer about its problems but leave it there. For instance, I have left some utterly wrong answers of my own up in this way so others could learn from my mistake.

If you find a post by another user that is obsolete or very bad, you can comment, vote to delete and/or flag.

In short, use the tools the platform has for dealing with bad content.