# Can I ask a moderator to unaccept my incorrect answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I wrote an answer that was accepted by a (new) user. Later I realised the algorithm I proposed contains a logical error, and it will not give the correct result. Some parts of the answer may still be useful, but as a whole it should clearly not be the accepted answer.

I have edited the answer to explain the error, and notified the user that he should unaccept the answer, but even though he's been online a couple of times since, he hasn't unaccepted the answer yet. Whether he's too inexperienced to know how to do that, or to understand why it's important, or hasn't noticed my comment, or just doesn't care, I don't know.

If the asker still hasn't acted after a week or so, is it possible to ask a moderator to unaccept the answer?

---

UPDATE

The asker just unaccepted the answer. I'll see if I can rewrite the answer to keep useful info and not mislead users into thinking it's a full working solution.

---

UPDATE

I completely reworked the answer into something that is not as efficient as the first version, but at least now it should return the correct result.

Comment: No. Un-/accepting is totally left to the OPs decision. Can't you improve your answer to be correct though?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've been thinking about it, but I haven't found a way to salvage the main part of the algorithm, and what I was trying to do may simply be impossible, at least with the complexity I was aiming for.

Comment: @m69 If you've edited your answer to explain the problem with it, and perhaps begin the answer with a statement to the effect of "I'm not sure this is possible, and what I have below doesn't actually solve it because of x, y, & z", then I don't see a problem with it remaining the accepted answer.

Comment: Behold the tremendous power of a 21 rep user.  Can single-handedly determine content at the web site, takes 8 users to undo again.  Can destroy the post of another user with just one action, only a moderator can do that.  Can destroy any edit to his post, only a moderator can stop that.  Can mark any post as the answer, wrong or right, nobody can do that.  Great power like that always comes with great responsibility, they don't have that either.  Whatever will be next after SO is somewhat likely to tweak that disparity, I imagine.  I hope.

Comment: My similar question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320480/my-upvoted-and-accepted-wrong-answer

Comment: You can ask the answer to be deleted and post another answer with the relevant information you want to keep.

Comment: Sometimes a bad answer gets accepted, and sometimes a great answer gets downvoted. And sometimes bad things happen to good people, and vice versa. Meh - let's go bowling.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Moderators don't have the power to accept or unaccept an answer.  It's up to the user who accepted to perform the unaccepting.

Comment: And even if they had the power, they still shouldn't do that.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems like you may have used your power to mark this as accepted.

Comment: @TravisJ If only that were true, all my answers would be accepted!!!  _<insert evil laugh>_

Comment: A mod can delete the answer, which unaccepts it.  If it's just an incorrect answer that the author realizes is wrong, that seems appropriate.

Comment: @Servy Yes, technically a moderator could delete an accepted answer but it's rare when a moderator would do that.

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, it would be rare, and this is exactly the unusual situation where it *would* be appropriate.  The answer is just wrong, the author realizes it, the answer *merits* deletion, but the system requires a moderator to delete it.  This isn't some case of the answer's author trying to vandalize the answer, which would be the reason to decline such a request.

Comment: @Servy 3 20k users can delete a negatively net scored answer as well - regardless of its accepted status.

Comment: @JonClements but it also need negatively scored answer - not every such post have enough negative votes. Organizing mass-downvte of own question and than deletion is interesting, but likely time-consuming task.

Comment: Compromise and disassociate the answer from the account?  That way the OP gets to keep the answer they felt helped them the most but the answerer is not stuck with a answer they do not like.

Comment: @NathanOliver That doesn't solve the problem of having a completely incorrect answer being suggested as the best answer to future readers.  That the answer isn't tied to the author anymore doesn't make it any less wrong.

Comment: @Servy: That's probably the compromise Nathan was referring to. A poor compromise if you ask me, considering the hoops a moderator has to jump through (namely, getting help from the CMs) to get a post disassociated. But then again, Stack Exchange *heavily* favors the asker anyway, so I don't think they'd care that it doesn't solve the problem of still having an incorrect answer - because it "helped" at least *one* person.

Comment: @BoltClock Well, it *didn't* help that one person.  Since they had an answer that they *thought* was correct, but that in reality wasn't, they're actually much *worse* off than if they hadn't seen the answer in the first place.  They're likely to go out and spend a bunch of time trying to implement the solution described, only to find out that they'd wasted their time as the approach is inherently flawed.  That they *thought* it helped them is actually the *problem* here.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, that's exactly why I put the word "helped" in scare quotes.

Comment: @BoltClock Fair enough.

Answer (score 15):

If you realize that the answer is simply wrong and doesn't answer the question, you can flag the post for moderator attention and ask that they delete the answer because you now realize that it's wrong, despite the fact that it's accepted.  While you can't delete your own accepted answer, a moderator can.

Comment: That's always an option. But maybe someone else can fix the flaw or use the information in the answer to come up with something better. I don't mind the answer being there, as long as the accepted icon doesn't mislead users about its status.

Comment: @m69 "maybe someone else can fix the flaw" tell that to the developers that saw with dismay a very obvious gaping security hole in a very popular answer and didn't do anything to fix it.

Comment: @m69 That you don't mind having an answer in your name that you know is wrong, misleading, and doesn't answer the question, whether accepted or not, is simply *baffling* to me.  Why in the world would you be so cruel to other people as to knowingly leave an answer that you know is wrong (and apparently in subtle enough ways that even you didn't realize how it's wrong at first).

Comment: _"If you realize that the answer is simply wrong and doesn't answer the question"_ Isn't it conflicting with the fact that the answer was **accepted** after all? It should require one hell of convincing to get a moderator to override the OP decision to accept the answer (I didn't downvote BTW)

Comment: @Servy As it is, the answer begins with the words " WARNING: The answer below contains a fatal flaw." I then go on to explain the error.

Comment: @AlonEitan People accept incorrect answers, or answers that don't answer the question.  This is an example of it.  It's certainly not impossible.

Comment: @m69 So you've got two options.  Either the reader notices and understands the warning, in which case you've just wasted their time, or they don't notice it (or don't understand it) and use the answer anyway, despite the fact that it's wrong.  Either way they don't come out ahead.

Comment: I'll state that I almost always delete accepted answers upon request by the answerer. If they recognize they posted a wrong answer, and want to delete it as such, I see no problem removing it upon request. There are maybe a handful of cases I'll decline where someone is trying to delete as part of a rage-quit, etc., but beyond that I accept the judgment of the person who posted the answer.

Comment: And I've once deleted an answer that the asker *maliciously accepted knowing it was wrong to spite the answerer*.

Comment: I was under the impression that moderators will unlikely to do that because the community can theoretically handle this by downvotes/close votes and finally delete votes. But I'm happy to see that there are some exceptions and that it's not totally pedantic, which make this answer the best IMHO

Comment: @Servy I completely reworked the answer, so there is no more risk that people read only half of the answer and copy the incorrect algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered...

## Editing your answer so that it *is* correct.

You've clearly already identified the problem and made note of it, but you can still edit that information into the answer itself (as well as changing the algorithm itself so that it does produce correct output).

Comment: This gets suggested every time. The real question is if the onus should fall on the answerer to keep their answer current and correct even - and *especially* - when it doesn't meet the asker's definition of correct. It doesn't seem fair to the answerer when the asker has the final say over whether their answer stays or goes. But I consider this to be a flaw in the accept feature more than anything else.

Comment: You're assuming that the answerer *knows* the correct answer.  They often won't, particularly in a case like this where the problem stems from the fact that the answerer didn't realize how difficult the problem actually was when they first answered.  Yes, it's nice *when possible*, but it will frequently simply not be possible.