# Is there a policy to un-accept answers by moderators?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

While I was searching for something, I recently stumbled across a question/answer where the accepted answer is wrong. So I flagged it with "**in need of moderator intervention**" with an comment that the answer is clearly wrong <sub>(and that the answerer deleted his answer, because I didn't know [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262423/what-does-a-greyed-out-answer-mean)...)</sub>.

I'm referring to this post (the answer was deleted after this post): <s>[Dynamically replace the contents of a C# method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method)</s>

However, my flag was declined with the reason:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

My point is not that it is wrong altogether, but that the answer is **accepted** even there are 8 other answers (some outdated, some are good) trying to address the question.

I know, it is usually the responsibility of the OP. But in such a case, 
how is the policy on Stack Overflow for this kind of question/answer states?

BTW: I do not suggest to accept another answer by the moderators, however, IMHO it is misleading if the accepted answer is the most wrong answer.

Comment: Sadly, SO (the company) wants to keep the accepted answer to the top, not the best answer (or in its defect, the most popular).

Comment: This is a different question, but the answer is the same: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349685/can-i-ask-a-moderator-to-unaccept-my-incorrect-answer  Short version is mods cannot accept or unaccept answers.  Only the OP can do it

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks for the link. That's fair enough. I was searching the HelpCenter but did not search meta.stackoverflow good enough...

Comment: The accept status of an answer is misleading in general, to be honest. It's really time to retire it, but our gracious hosts still think that it has value to know what answer worked for the question author... In this case apparently, I have to assume the author was persuaded to not want to implement this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accepting is purely at the discretion of the post author. Mods are never going to accept or unaccept an answer.

A score of -23 is a pretty clear indicator the answer is wrong. The accepted mark isn't going to change that.

If anything, you can try to recruit >20K rep users to pursue deletion of the answer if you're sure it holds no value or is actively distracting.

Comment: This is correct, but to clarify an important point: it's not that ♦ moderators *won't* changed the accepted or unaccepted status of an answer but that we *can't* do so.