# Who marks green tick in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Who marks green tick in Stack Overflow and which parameters are responsible?

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to SO - please read all of the community guidance, as most of your questions will be answered there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: A few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages at SO will be very useful in teaching you how the site works.

Comment: Indeed, the tour explains it right at the top. Very much worth it.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349685/can-i-ask-a-moderator-to-unaccept-my-incorrect-answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The green tick is marked by the person who asked the question.

The onus is on them to choose who has produced the best answer and mark that as the 'Accepted Answer'.  This then generates the green tick that you can see.

You can also indicate where answers are of value (but maybe not, in your opinion, the best one) by upvoting the answer.